# Prefix input value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am creating a form and dynamically populating a field using php so the field value looks like this `01-02-2015-01`. I need to prefix the value with a number depending on the value of a select box. So `if ( condition )` the prefix will look be 888 so the input value is now `888-01-02-2015-01`. I need to do this dynamically so javascript/jQuery is what I need to use. Any help out be appreciated.

Comment: And what's the condition? If you know that, where are you stuck?

Comment: For such purpose what have you tried so far?

Comment: I am not sure how to add the value.  The value is already set using php so I need to just prefix the 888 to the value depending on the select option. `If the selection options is 1 then prefix 888 else 800. `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested code, but probably should work

Html :

```
<select id='currency'>
  <option val='$'>$</option>
  <option val='Rs.'>Rs.</option>
</select>
Amount : <input type='text' value='1200' id='amount'/>
```

Jquery :

```
  $(function(){
     $("#currency").change(function(){
       var symbol = $(this).val();
       var currentValue = $('#amount').val();
       $.each(['$','Rs.'],function(i, a){
         if(currentValue.indexOf(a)==0){  //if the currentValue starts with any matching symbol, then remove it.
           currentValue = currentValue.replace(a,'');
         }
       });
       $("#amount").val(symbol + ' ' + currentValue);
     });

    //In order to fire change manually, do this
    $("#currency").change();
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked out great. The only issue is the value only updated on change. How can I evaluate the value when the form is initially loaded?

Comment: Thank you. One last issue. When changing the select box the space between the `symbol and currentValue` does not reset. Have a look here if you can. https://jsfiddle.net/2f99m227/ I replaced the space with a hyphen to demonstrate. If you change the select box then the hyphen is duplicated. '-----' Any idea why?

Comment: because we're replacing only the symbol inside `$.each` callback, replace the `-` also. There you go - https://jsfiddle.net/nitincool4urchat/2f99m227/1/

Comment: Nice! Thank you very much.